# Usage of timesince built in tag in Django Applications

Tags: django

I like to use the timesince built-in tag to get the number of the days that have occurred since the event.. The documentation for the tag is found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince

But when i implement it, it returns me the data in weeks and somtimes in minutes.. I would only like the value to be in days... I am not sure how to change the filter to get the days...

Need some guidance... Thanks..

Comment: I don't think you can do that with _timesince_ filter. It automatically translates in humanized form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a very simple [template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters):

```
import datetime

@register.filter(name='days_since')
def days_since(value):
    since = 0
    try:
        since = (datetime.datetime.now() - value).days
    except:
        pass
    return since


...

{{ obj.date|days_since }}
```